# Firebug console, giving error "function not defined"

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, function

I am trying to submit a form through Ajax, but it is not calling the function?

I'm getting this error on the Firebug console:

```
ReferenceError: CreateUser is not defined
CreateUser()
```

The button I am using to call this function:

```
<input type="button" onclick="CreateUser()" id="RegisterUserBtn" class="btn" value="Sign Up" name="">
```

My function:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function(e){

        function  CreateUser(){
            alert('CreateUser SignUp button is clicked.');
        }
    });

</script>
```

What is causing this issue? Why cant it find the function name?

Comment: Declaring `function` outside `document.ready` will solve it.

Comment: @DipeshParmar
Yup you are right, needed it to declare outside of document.ready
thankyou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a closure around your `CreateUser` function by putting it inside of an anonymous function. `CreateUser` is "local" to the scope of the containing function and is not exposed to the global scope where your onclick event is being defined.

Simply take the function outside of the `$(document).ready` block.

Comment: My mistake, i didn't needed to define it under the `$(document).ready`.
Its working now. Thanks..

Answer (score 4):

You are mixing two styles of javascript-coding here:  "old style" with on-event attributes in your html code. and "unobstrusive javascript" with the $(document).ready block.
My recommendation would be to use unobstrusive javascript consistently:

Don't use onclick in your html.  jQuery helps you keep all Javascript out of your html code. You already have an ID for you button.

```
<input type="button"  id="RegisterUserBtn" class="btn" value="Sign Up" name="">
```

so your jQuery could look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    function CreateUser() {
        alert('CreateUser SignUp button is clicked.');
    }
    $('#RegisterUserBtn').on('click', CreateUser);
});
```

This separation of HTML and Javascript is called "unobstrusive javascript".

See a live Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/bjelline/nySxm/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jquery then try this instead

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function(e){

       $("#RegisterUserBtn").click(function(){
            alert('CreateUser SignUp button is clicked.');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

if your want to run `CreateUser` function on click event, then remove `$(document).ready` function and declare your function inside  title. The functions inside  `$(document).ready` load after the content load. your html is loaded before the function declaration .

Or you may use jquery [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

   $('#RegisterUserBtn').on('click', function() {
       alert('CreateUser SignUp button is clicked.');
   });

});
```